# JQ: deleting unnecessary keys and re-formatting the JSON - most efficient ways

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, jq

I have two questions to ask. Here is the JSON file below.

```
[
    {
        "Header": {
            "Region": "DC1"
        },
        "Body": [
            {
                "agentMetaInfoDtos": [],
                "avgTraffic": 682,
                "minAgentVersion": "1.191.0.20180101-000000",
                "standardAgentVersion": null,
                "tenantState": "ACTIVE",
                "tenantUuid": "DC1-Tenant1"
            },
            {
                "agentMetaInfoDtos": [],
                "avgTraffic": 957,
                "minAgentVersion": "1.185.0.20180101-000000",
                "standardAgentVersion": null,
                "tenantState": "DISABLED",
                "tenantUuid": "DC1-Tenant2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Header": {
            "Region": "DC2"
        },
        "Body": [
            {
                "agentMetaInfoDtos": [],
                "avgTraffic": 690,
                "minAgentVersion": "1.163.0.20180101-000000",
                "standardAgentVersion": null,
                "tenantState": "ACTIVE",
                "tenantUuid": "DC2-t4-p1"
            },
            {
                "agentMetaInfoDtos": [],
                "avgTraffic": 2441,
                "minAgentVersion": "1.161.0.20180101-000000",
                "standardAgentVersion": null,
                "tenantState": "ACTIVE",
                "tenantUuid": "DC2-t5-p2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Header": {
            "Region": "DC3"
        },
        "Body": [
            {
                "agentMetaInfoDtos": [],
                "avgTraffic": 2046,
                "minAgentVersion": "1.169.0.20180101-000000",
                "standardAgentVersion": null,
                "tenantState": "ACTIVE",
                "tenantUuid": "DC3-r1-p1"
            },
            {
                "agentMetaInfoDtos": [],
                "avgTraffic": 0,
                "minAgentVersion": null,
                "standardAgentVersion": null,
                "tenantState": "FORSAKEN",
                "tenantUuid": "DC3-r2-d1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

First, I want to delete unnecessary keys and re-format the JSON. I want to have the result look like following

```
[
  {
    "Region": "DC1",
    "Tenants": [
      {
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE",
        "tenantUuid": "DC1-Tenant1"
      },
      {
        "tenantState": "DISABLED",
        "tenantUuid": "DC1-Tenant2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Region": "DC2",
    "Tenants": [
      {
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE",
        "tenantUuid": "DC2-t4-p1"
      },
      {
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE",
        "tenantUuid": "DC2-t5-p2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Region": "DC3",
    "Tenants": [
      {
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE",
        "tenantUuid": "DC3-r1-p1"
      },
      {
        "tenantState": "FORSAKEN",
        "tenantUuid": "DC3-r2-d1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My brute-force (let's say dumb) filter is the following - delete everyting not needed an (BTW, below are just subset of keys I need to delete, there are more):

```
del (.[].Body[].agentMetaInfoDtos) | del (.[].Body[].avgTraffic)  | del (.[].Body[].minAgentVersion) | del (.[].Body[].standardAgentVersion) | del (.[].Body[].serverDistribution)  |  [.[] | {"Region": .Header.Region, Tenants:[ .Body[]] } ]
```

But there should be a much better way to do this - just selecting only what is needed instead of deleting everything else. BTW, in the `Body[]` section it is always the same number of keys, it is content in `agentMetaInfoDtos[]` and other arrays/keys which are different. `tenantState` can have five different values.

First, tried to use the following filter trying to select the right keys, instead of deleting everything else:

```
[.[] | {Region: .Header.Region, Tenants:[ {tenantUuid: .Body[].tenantUuid, tenantState: .Body[].tenantState} ] }]
```

But the result is the duplication of key/values as below.

I am sure there are multiple ways to accomplish what I want, could someone give a crash course or at least point in the right direction?

```
[
  {
    "Region": "DC1",
    "Tenants": [
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC1-Tenant1",
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC1-Tenant1",
        "tenantState": "DISABLED"
      },
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC1-Tenant2",
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC1-Tenant2",
        "tenantState": "DISABLED"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Region": "DC2",
    "Tenants": [
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC2-t4-p1",
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC2-t4-p1",
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC2-t5-p2",
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC2-t5-p2",
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Region": "DC3",
    "Tenants": [
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC3-r1-p1",
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC3-r1-p1",
        "tenantState": "FORSAKEN"
      },
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC3-r2-d1",
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "tenantUuid": "DC3-r2-d1",
        "tenantState": "FORSAKEN"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And the second question - even when I had the result, after that I wanted to filter it out further to have only the entries with the state DISABLED. So I used the filter
 `map(select (.Tenants[].tenantState == "DISABLED" ))` but the result displays both Active and disabled tenants in the DC3 as seen below.

Any hint what I am doing wrong here?

```
[
  {
    "Region": "DC1",
    "Tenants": [
      {
        "tenantState": "ACTIVE",
        "tenantUuid": "DC1-Tenant1"
      },
      {
        "tenantState": "DISABLED",
        "tenantUuid": "DC1-Tenant2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. Just did it.

Comment: You should not think of it as "deleting things and rearranging everything else," that is not an intuitive way to look at things in general. Instead, you should think of it as "extracting important bits of data and presenting it as I need it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Part 1

The first part of the question is easily answered by expanding .Body just once:

```
[.[] | {Region: .Header.Region, Tenants: [.Body[] | {tenantUuid, tenantState}] }]
```

### Part 2

To simplify the exposition here, let's filter the result obtained above. If we want to modify .Tenants to include only objects with .tenantState == "DISABLED" we could add the following filter to the pipeline:

```
map( .Tenants |= map(select(.tenantState == "DISABLED")) )
```

The Q, however, suggests that empty arrays should be excluded from the final result, so we could further tack on:

```
map( select(.Tenants != []) )
```

### In summary

Putting the above together:

```
[.[] | {Region: .Header.Region, Tenants: [.Body[] | {tenantUuid, tenantState}] }]
| map( .Tenants |= map(select(.tenantState == "DISABLED")) )
| map( select(.Tenants != []) )
```

Of course, it would be more efficient to perform the selection earlier in the pipeline -- by all means, have at it!